# What is this property exhibited by some logical systems?

Tags: lo.logic, terminology, proof-theory

I'm migrating [this question from MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420887/what-is-this-property-exhibited-by-some-logical-systems) to MO, as in the span of five months, it received 6 upvotes but no answers. If my language needs to be fine-tuned in any way, constructive suggestions and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

---

The following property exhibited by some logical systems has captured my attention:

$$\forall X\; ( {\vdash x_1[X]} \implies {\vdash x_2[X]} ) \implies \forall X\; {\vdash (x_1[X]\to x_2[X])},$$

where $X$ ranges over "ways to fill in the holes in $x_1$ and $x_2$", for any syntactically correct schemas $x_1$ and $x_2$.

In other words, the property states that if $x_2[X]$ is provable whenever $x_1[X]$ is provable, then all instances of the schema ($x_1 \rightarrow x_2$) are also provable.

Some examples off the top of my head of where this property *does not* hold:

- Classical predicate logic *does not* have this property because (letting $x_1[P] = P$ and letting $x_2[P] = \forall x.P$), it is necessarily true that $(\vdash P) \implies (\vdash \forall x.P)$, but it is *not* necessarily true that $\vdash (P \rightarrow \forall x.P)$
- Intuitionistic logic *does not* have this property because (letting $x_1[A, B, C] = \neg A\to B\lor C$ and letting $x_2[A, B, C] = (\neg A\to B)\lor(\neg A\to C))$, it is necessarily true that $(\vdash\neg A\to B\lor C)\implies(\vdash(\neg A\to B)\lor(\neg A\to C))$, but it is *not* necessarily true that $\vdash(\neg A\to B\lor C)\rightarrow((\neg A\to B)\lor(\neg A\to C))$.

My question is 3-fold:

1. Does this property have a name? If so, what is it called?
2. Does classical *propositional* logic have this property? (I'm assuming it does, but I want to be sure.) What other systems display this property?
3. Does the presence of this property (or lack thereof) imply any other important properties about the system in question? (I realize that this third part of the question might seem overly broad, but what I really want to know is: is this property *important* and if so, *why*? Deep insights appreciated.)

Partial answers welcomed as well.

Comment: Can $x_1, x_2$ contain fixed variables ? As in $x_1[A] = A\implies B$ ?

Comment: @Max no. But you could do $x_1[A, B] = A$ and $x_2[A, B] = B$

Comment: Looks like some kind of deduction theorem.

Comment: @EvgenyKuznetsov yes, it does! However, the deduction theorem holds in intuitionistic logic, whereas this property does not.

Comment: @Hans Brende Yes I see.

Comment: While intuitionistic logic, indeed, does not have the property, the argument in the question is wrong: for example, taking $\neg\neg p\to p$ for $A$, and $\neg p$ for $B$, we have $\vdash(A\to B)\to A$, but $\nvdash A$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Brilliant! Thank you for the counter-example! I will amend my question to say that "*minimal* logic does not have this property" (as the proof of your counterexample requires the step $\bot\to p$ as far as I can see). That being the case, do you have an example that shows why this property does not hold for intuitionistic logic?

Comment: Your example does not work for minimal logic either, just take $A=(((p\to q)\to p)\to p)$, $B=(p\to q)$. Well-known rules admissible but not derivable in intuitionistic logic include the independence of premise (aka Harrop's) rule $\vdash\neg A\to B\lor C\implies\vdash(\neg A\to B)\lor(\neg A\to C)$, the Scott rule $\vdash(\neg\neg A\to A)\to A\lor\neg A\implies\vdash\neg\neg A\lor\neg A$, or Mints's rule $\vdash(A\to B)\to A\lor C\implies\vdash((A\to B)\to A)\lor((A\to B)\to C)$. The more general Visser's rules are, I believe, mentioned on the Wikipedia page I linked from my answer.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek wonderful! Your counter-examples are gold! I've updated my question with Harrop's rule, thank you very much for the suggestions.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek do you happen to know whether or not minimal logic has this property?

Comment: No, for instance the Mints or Visser rules are also admissible in minimal logic. (In general, it holds that a rule expressed using only positive connectives is admissible in minimal logic if and only if it is admissible in intuitionistic logic.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is equivalent to a combination of *structual completeness* with the *deduction theorem*. For a start, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_rule).

Comment: The information contained in this answer and your comments above is, I repeat, *gold*. I've been pouring over the wikipedia article, but one thing it doesn't seem to touch on too much is part 3 of my question: the *implications* of structural completeness. Aside from the inherent beauty evident to me in such a system that, in a sense, *perfectly describes itself*, are there other advantages inherent in such a system? Theorems? Connections to other concepts (e.g. *Gödel* completeness)? I want to know why this property mesmerizes me :) Also, are there structurally complete predicate logics?

Comment: I can’t think of any implications for other properties of the logic. Concerning predicate logics: it may depend on how you define “predicate logic” (I am going to assume it is at least closed under formula substitution), but no, not really, if you stick to reasonable logics that would appear in the literature. For an example of what can go wrong, consider the formula $A=\exists x\,\exists y\,(P(x)\land\neg P(y))$. There are two possibilities: (1) No instance of $A$ is provable. Then by structural completeness, $\neg A$ is provable, hence so are all its instances. Since this amounts to all ...

Comment: ... individuals having the same properties, this is effectively a propositional logic, the quantifiers are redundant. (2) Some instance $A'=\sigma(A)$ of $A$ is provable. Thus, the logic itself proves that there exist at least two elements distinguished by their properties. But what’s more, the logic has to prove all instances of $A'$ as well, even if, for example, we substitute all predicates in $A'$ with a trivially true formula! It is not really possible for a formula of this form to have different truth values for different elements, thus the logic is really inconsistent. ...

Comment: ... But maybe the logic includes “logical predicates” such as $x=y$, that cannot be substituted? Well, then let $A$ be the sentence using just $=$ which says that the universe has at least $42$ elements. Again, either $A$ is provable, or, by structural completeness, $\neg A$ is provable. This can be of course done for all finite numbers, not just $42$, Thus, either there is a fixed integer $k$ such that the logic proves that all models have exactly $k$ elements, or it proves that all models are infinite. In the latter case, the fun continues. Let $A$ be a sentence expressing ...

Comment: ... a nontrivial theory, such as the conjunction of axioms of dense linear orders, or of Robinson arithmetic. Again, either (1) the logic proves an instance of $A$, or (2) it proves $\neg A$. In case (1), it means the logic has to somehow have a built-in dense order, or arithmetic, or whatever, in such a way that it cannot be substituted away. In case (2), the logic proves that no such thing as a dense linear order can be definable in any model. Neither of these possibilities is remotely reasonable for a “logic”.